# Build war including WebContent of another project in main service project

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-war-plugin

I have a project having current file structure as(This works fine):

```
project-services
    - src/main/java
    - WebContent
    - pom.xml
```

project-services pom.xml

```
...
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
...
```

I have to move WebContent of to project-services to project-ui as:

```
project-services
    - src/main/java
    - pom.xml
project-ui
    - pom.xml
    - WebContent
```

Now I have to build war including `WebContent` of `project-ui` in `project-services`.

What modification I have to do in `project-services's pom.xml` to work as it was previously?

Comment: Follow convention over configuration paradigm and put things into `src/main/webapp` instead...

Answer (score 0):

You need a parent pom like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.greg</groupId>
    <artifactId>multi-module-example</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>multi-module-example</name>

    <modules>
        <module>services</module>
        <module>web</module>
    </modules>

</project>
```

With 2 projects in it, one for the services and one for the webapp

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
            <artifactId>multi-module-example</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.greg</groupId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </parent>

        <artifactId>services</artifactId>

        <dependencies>
            <!-- dependencies -->
        </dependencies>

    </project>
```

Then the web pom has a dependency to the services at the project version

As has been said, keep to the maven convention for the directory sturcture.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
            <artifactId>multi-module-example</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.greg</groupId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </parent>

        <artifactId>web</artifactId>
        <packaging>war</packaging>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.greg</groupId>
                <artifactId>services</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- other dependencies -->
        </dependencies>

        <build>
            <finalName>web</finalName>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </project>
```

when you build the parent it will build the services jar, then the web war.